# De-Extinction Candidates

Tags: fauna, flora, extinction

I know the classic deextinction candidates such as the passenger pigeon or wooly mammoth. What other animals do we have the potential to revive? Are there any odd candidates such as other mastodons or ground sloths we have a possibility to revive other than the popular candidates? (I would love to hear about plant species too!!)

Edit: Im looking for prehistoric creatures, not creatures that have gone extinct within the last few centuries.

Comment: Are you looking for prehistoric creatures? Your question is vague in describing exactly what you need.

Comment: De-extinction requires we have effectively 100% of the genome available (forget patching with frog DNA like in the first *Jurassic Park* movie).  Not many long-lost critters meet that criterion...

Comment: Just asking for a list seems like it is a bit off-topic here, to be honest.

Comment: Bring back the pterodactyl! My parakeet is getting a bit too snooty and I want to put her in her place. How are we to judge the millions of list entries? Without criteria, seems both too broad and opinion-based.

Comment: @ user535733 What criteria would you suggest? I've thought about some but I cant really brainstorm any good ideas.

Comment: @Thalassan Ultimately, to answer this question you need to know what the requirements are for being able to recreate an extinct animal. I would re-write your question to ask what these requirements are. A good answer explaining those requirements will allow you to devise a list of extinct plants and animals that fit those criteria.

Comment: There is some evidence that certain pterodactyl and sauropod like dinosaurs still live in parts of central Africa.

Comment: Is your intention for these lifeforms to be able to live in the wild, or in a controlled environment? If it's the former, it will be nearly impossible to keep them alive since food sources are different, oxygen content in the atmosphere is different, etc.